# How to cut n paste text and pictures from a web page into LibreOffice 5.2?

Tags: libreoffice, cut-and-paste

I'm trying to cut n paste a blog article into a new writer document using LibreOffice 5.2, but ctrl+V just gets text with a generic picture and not what was on the web page.  I'm using Firefox, but I suspect IE would give the same result. I also tried ctrl+shift+V, but it didn't work either.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Essentially, with a web page, WYSINWYG "what you see is not what you get" The underlying code isn't visible to a simple copy/paste. The closest you can get without dissecting the underlying html/css is to just screen-shot the page; that's WYSIWYG, I'm afraid.

Comment: Or manually cut n paste each picture into the document.  I've done that before, but I  thought LibreOffice had a feature for this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the sections of text, as usual. For each image, right click and 'Save image as...' Then in LibreOffice use the Insert menu at the top to insert the image.

Answer (score -1):

I keep a 2007 version of WORD on my computer just for the purpose of copying and pasting text and pix from a web site. I later open the document in Libre Office Writer and save it in odt format.